# How to use OmniFaces in junit

Tags: jsf-2, junit, mocking, mockito, omnifaces

in my test method i want to be able to call `Ajax.oncomplete` which internally make calls to:

```
OmniPartialViewContext.getCurrentInstance
```

please advise how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have accomplished that as follows:

**1- use FacesContextMocker class:**

```
public abstract class FacesContextMocker extends FacesContext {
    private FacesContextMocker() {
    }

    private static final Release RELEASE = new Release();

    private static class Release implements Answer<Void> {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            setCurrentInstance(null);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static FacesContext mockFacesContext() {
        FacesContext context = Mockito.mock(FacesContext.class);
        setCurrentInstance(context);
        Mockito.doAnswer(RELEASE).when(context).release();
        return context;
    }
}
```

**2- mock OmniPartialViewContext the object as follows:**

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContextMocker.mockFacesContext();

        // mocking omnifaces OmniPartialViewContext to test Ajax.oncomplete
        OmniPartialViewContext omniPartialViewContext = Mockito
                .mock(OmniPartialViewContext.class);
        Map<Object, Object> map = facesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getAttributes();
        map.put(OmniPartialViewContext.class.getName(), omniPartialViewContext);
        Mockito.when(facesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes())
                .thenReturn(map);
```

Comment: Indeed, I was about to post a comment that it's just stored as `FacesContext` attribute with `OmniPartialViewContext.class.getName()` as key.